# [CIContext initWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170400960 in xcode8

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios8.3

**run in ios8.3 ,but run in ios9 or 10 hasn't this problem.**

```
-[CIContext initWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170400960
2016-09-19 18:08:21.025 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CIContext initWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170400960'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186d8c2d8 0x1985b00e4 0x186d933a4 0x186d90154 0x186c92ccc 0x1001c1e74 0x1001c1b7c 0x1001c143c 0x1001c1cfc 0x100311e0c 0x1003116d0 0x1001d7690 0x101f3025c 0x101f2fc08 0x101eee29c 0x103db8fd4 0x103db8f94 0x103dbdc28 0x186d437f8 0x186d418a0 0x186c6d2d4 0x1904836fc 0x18b832fac 0x100401fd8 0x198c2ea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I think we have no solution... https://openradar.appspot.com/28200846

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the crash report, it seems that Xcode 8 has some issue converting the Swift method `CIContext(options: [String : Any]?)` to its Objective-C counterpart `+ (CIContext *)contextWithOptions:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options;`.

Instead it is converted as `-[CIContext initWithOptions:]` hence the unrecognized selector.

One possible workaround is to declare an Objective-C category like this:

```
@interface CIContext (Workaround)

+ (CIContext *)yourprefix_contextWithOptions:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation CIContext (Workaround)

+ (CIContext *)yourprefix_contextWithOptions:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
    return [CIContext contextWithOptions:options];
}

@end
```

Then import this category in your module bridging header and replace your original CIContext init call with the one from this category.

I imagine this is a compilation issue that can be fixed with an Xcode update. In the meantime, this workaround may be helpful.