# Swift3.0 Xcode8 iOS7 CIContext(options: nil) Crash

Tags: ios, ios7, swift3, xcode8

The following code works fine in Swift2.2 of iOS7+, Swift3.0 of iOS8+,  would crash only in Swift3.0 iOS7.

`let context = CIContext(options: nil)`

The console info:

> -[CIContext initWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x147366e0 2016-10-25 17:32:27.903 CMBMobile DEV[1017:4403] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CIContext initWithOptions:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147366e0'

I tried to change it into 

`let context = CIContext()`

But it seems the instance of context is not been initialize for the address of it is `0x00000000`.And when I call `context.createCGImage(ciimage, from: originRect)` returns unexpected nil.

Comment: It's probably a Xcode 8 bug.[cicontext-initwithoptions-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570644/cicontext-initwithoptions-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x170400960) fix it

Answer (score 0):

As Swift 3 is compatible only for iOS 8+, it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3.0, this is a bug by Apple.
You can create a Category for CIContext.

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

@interface CIContext (FixBug)
+ (CIContext *)swiftContextWithOptions:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options;

@end


#import "CIContext+FixBug.h"
@implementation CIContext (FixBug)
+ (CIContext *)swiftContextWithOptions:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    return [CIContext contextWithOptions:options];
}
@end
```

And you should use this function.

```
let context = CIContext.swiftContext(options: [kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false])
```